# I need to put a vector formula into a data validation cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to put a formula into Data Validation for a List, I do this with a formula because I need the list to change items according to other parameters and I can't paste the formula in a range and the reference the cell in the data validation beacuse it needs to be done several times.

The formula is the following

```
=IFS(A1="Normal", UNIQUE(TARIFARIO_1[City]), A1="Multimedios", UNIQUE(TARIFARIO_2[CITY]))
```

The list should change based on the value of A column, and 'TARIFARIO_1' and 'TARIFARIO_2' are both tables. I searched and seems that is not posible to do it but i don't know if there is a work around this because as I mentioned earlier referencing a range that contains the formula is not an option.

Appreciate the help.